# React- only run file once external js file loaded (gapi not defined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gmail-api

I am trying to use the gmail API with React.js.

I keep getting the error 'gapi is not defined'. I believe my `client.js` file in the HTML is loading after my `mail.js` file runs?

How can I get around this?

**Index.html**

```
...
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
```

**Index.js**

```
import './Mail.js';
```

**Mail.js**

```
import { createAction, handleActions } from 'redux-actions'

const CLIENT_ID = '1.apps.googleusercontent.com'
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']

export const SET_GMAIL_CREDENTIALS = 'SET_GMAIL_CREDENTIALS'
export const CHANGE_LOADING = 'CHANGE_LOADING'
export const SET_GMAIL_LABELS = 'SET_GMAIL_LABELS'
export const SELECT_GMAIL_LABEL = 'SELECT_GMAIL_LABEL'
export const SET_GMAIL_EMAILS = 'SET_GMAIL_EMAILS'

let defaultState = {
  profile: {
    emailAddress: ''
  },
  loading: true,
  labels: [],
  currentLabel: null,
  emails: []
}

export const connect = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch(turnLoadingOn())
    gmailAuth(false, populateCredentials(dispatch), clearCredentials(dispatch))
  }
}...
```

Comment: is your gmail-api script tag after your bundled react/application script tag?

Answer (score 6):

I think you're right. The way I'm handling these situations is by loading the external JS file from React and using it in a promise.

So your flow should be something like this:

1. React app loads
2. React app injects your file in the HTML
3. Do your thing in step 2's callback or .then()

Create a helper function. Put it in a folder like `helpers/load-script`. Below you have all the code you should have in that file:

```js
export default function loadScript(url, cb) {

      var scr = document.createElement('script');
      scr.type = 'text/javascript';

      if (scr.readyState) { // IE
        scr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (scr.readyState ==`loaded' || scr.readyState ==='complete') {
            scr.onreadystatechange = null;
            cb();
          }
        };
      } else { // Others
        scr.onload = cb;
      }

      script.src = url;
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scr);
    }
```

Next, import that function inside the component you want to use it into:

```js
import React from 'react';
import loadScript from 'helpers/load-script';

class testComponent extends React.Component {
    
  componentDidMount() {
    loadScript('https://apis.google.com/js/client.js', () => {
    // do mail api stuff here               
    });
  }
   
  render() {
    return (
      <div>hi there</div>
    );
  }
}

export default testComponent;
```

Comment: Could you please give me a more comprehensive example? I've pasted your code sample into my `Mail.js` and I continue to get `gapi undefined`

Comment: I hope you replaced the 'your-external-file.js' thing :D I'm editting the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with GrowSurf Javascript Web API, The external script loaded after the render function, and its function was being undefined in `componentDidMount()`.
This is a logic I used to get the GrowSurf function not to be undefined. It can also help anyone who wants to use a function of any external JS introduced in index.html.

You can use `DOMSubtreeModified` in `componentDidMount()` to check every time the DOM is modified, once the external JS is loaded(found) run your function there, and then stop the looping of `DOMSubtreeModified`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let functionDefined = false;
    window.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        if(!functionDefined) {
            if (window.growsurf) {
                console.log('a function is defined', window.growsurf.getReferrerId());
                functionDefined = true;
            }
        }   
    }, false);
}
```

For your case, you can simply do this.

```
componentDidMount() {
    let functionDefined = false;
    window.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
        if(!functionDefined) {
            if (window.gapi) {
                // do mail api stuff here       
                functionDefined = true;
            }
        }   
    }, false);
}
```